# Movilizer - getQuestionClientKey() only working when text is declared?

Tags: mobility, movilizer

Given the following code:

```
<question key="Q(Acciones)0" title="" type="6">
     <answer attributeType="72" key="Q(Acciones)_0" nextQuestionKey="Q(Acciones)1" position="0" >
      <predefinedValue>x</predefinedValue>
       </answer>                        
  <answer attributeType="14" columnSizeType="ROWS" key="editarcliente" clientKey="editarcliente" nextQuestionKey="Q(Acciones)1" position="0" icon="30" >
          <text>.</text> 
   </answer>                  
    <answer attributeType="14" columnSizeType="ROWS" key="mapa" clientKey="mapa"  nextQuestionKey="Q(Acciones)1" position="1" icon="12" >
      <text>.</text>
   </answer>  
   <answer attributeType="14" columnSizeType="ROWS" key="detalles" clientKey="detalles" nextQuestionKey="Q(Acciones)1" position="2" icon="23">
       <text>.</text> 
   </answer>  
     <onEnterAssignment>                        

     </onEnterAssignment>
     <onLeaveOkPersistAssignment>
          $global:buton_click = getQuestionClientKey();                                                      
     </onLeaveOkPersistAssignment>                                                   
     <complex linearGroupId="G(FichaCliente)" gridGroupId="G(FichaCliente)" groupTitle="Flash" gridHorizontalLayout="false" gridInnerScrollbar="true" linearInnerScrollbar="true"  linearPos="4" gridPosX="0" gridPosY="2" gridWidth="3" gridHeight="4" linearHeight="3" />
 </question>
```

When calling "getQuestionClientKey();" it returns the clientkey only when the text "." is declared and with a value. We would like to remove this text but still get the client key. Is this possible?

Comment: Are the attribute types and column size types having any effect in this menu screen? Regarding your original question my expectation is that the text is optional.

Comment: The issue is fixed with the newest 2.3 clients

Answer (score 0):

Just tested with:

- empty text element
- spaces in text element
- tabs in text element

both getQuestionKey and getQuestionClientKey returned nothing in all of these cases.
I'll create a support issue.